# symfony2 access denied exception

Tags: php, symfony, web

i'm working on symfony2 project and i get this exception. anybody have an idea on what is causing it ?

Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException' with message 'Access Denied' in /data/apache/www/emploipublic-sf/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:70\n

```
class AccessListener implements ListenerInterface
{  
private $context;
private $accessDecisionManager;
private $map;
private $authManager;
private $logger;

public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $context, AccessDecisionManagerInterface $accessDecisionManager, AccessMapInterface $map, AuthenticationManagerInterface $authManager, LoggerInterface $logger = null)
{
    $this->context = $context;
    $this->accessDecisionManager = $accessDecisionManager;
    $this->map = $map;
    $this->authManager = $authManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

/**
 * Handles access authorization.
 *
 * @param GetResponseEvent $event A GetResponseEvent instance
 */
public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (null === $token = $this->context->getToken()) {
        throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException('A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.');
    }

    $request = $event->getRequest();

    list($attributes, $channel) = $this->map->getPatterns($request);

    if (null === $attributes) {
        return;
    }

    if (!$token->isAuthenticated()) {
        $token = $this->authManager->authenticate($token);
        $this->context->setToken($token);
    }

    if (!$this->accessDecisionManager->decide($token, $attributes, $request)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();  // this is line 70
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is the "symfony1" in the title a typo?

Comment: As for the error, it seems pretty clear. Presumably somewhere you have some access restrictions configured, or there are default ones in the template project. Have you tried searching for "configure authentication in Symfony2" or similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your `security.yml` file (`app/config/security.yml`).

You may have some secure path which you do not have access to. Check out

> security -> access_control

section.

Comment: Thanks it helped to resolve the problem. The following worked


`- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER } `

Comment: Alex is right. You're trying to access a page behind a firewall. You must be authenticated first.

 [Check the Symfony security manuel for more infos][1]


  [1]: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html