# Symfony 4: ROLE_USER doesn't inherit IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY and Voter throws AccessDeniedException

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, fosuserbundle

I'm working on a legacy project with a lot of ancient staffs. There're huge numbers of actions which are used really rare. Half a year ago we upgraded from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 4.4. All worked pretty well until a manager tried to use one of the old action that now returns `AccessDeniedException: Access Denied.`

I've checked Symfony documentation and all seems pretty straightforward for me.

[The documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully) says:

> **Checking to see if a User is Logged In (IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY)**
>
> If you only want to check if a user is logged in (you don’t care about roles), you have two options. First, if you’ve given every user ROLE_USER, you can check for that role.

There is `app/config/security.yml` with the next configuration:

```yaml
security:
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
        allow_if_all_abstain: true

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN_CAN_EDIT_PERMISSIONS: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN_CAN_EDIT_PERMISSIONS

    providers:
          fos_user:
              id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_user
                default_target_path: /user-post-login
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                login_path: user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
                handlers: [mp.logout_handler]
                invalidate_session: false
            anonymous: ~
            remember_me:
                secret:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
                path:     /
                domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        ...
        - { path: ^/api, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        ...
        - { path: ^/admin/select-customer-status, role: [ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
        ...
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_USER }
```

My current user has the role `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`, according to `role_hierarchy` this role has `ROLE_USER` in ancestors, but when I try to open http://localhost:8080/admin/select-customer-status/1 I get this `Access Denied` exception.

I tried to debug and figured out this exception arose in [`Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php#L90-L96)

[image]

But the real problem is that `Voter` is checking for `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` [under the hood](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/AuthenticatedVoter.php#L46-L50), but this one isn't present in `$attributes`.

Another interesting thing is when I add this configuration directly to Action it works as expected and no exception is thrown:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/admin/update-user-permissions/{id}", name="update_user_permissions")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 * 
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN")
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN")
 */
```

Can anybody help with this strange behaviour?

P.S. There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027766/symfony2-access-denied-exception), but it's for Symfony 2 and not reliable for me.

Comment: the voter you linked only casts its vote if the attribute is one of the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_*` kind (continues otherwise and finally returns abstain, since no other result is set), so it's probably not the culprit. in fact, in dev mode, there is a security tab in the profiler that shows the results from all voters. please check which one actually denies access.

Comment: most likely not it, but have you tried setting `roles` instead of `role` in your `access_control`? all examples I've seen in the docs appear to use `roles` and the fact that there are multiple might have some effect ;o) your annotation version however should require a user to have *both* roles.

Comment: @Jakumi, here is [a screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/yrWFkqy) of Security tab. I cannot understand what is wrong.

Comment: I've tried to change `role` to `roles` but this has no impact.

Comment: the screenshot you posted seems to suggest, that the user has to have *both* roles, which is not the case for a user only holding one of those two roles. either you somehow introduce the or (as in the answer below) or you declare a common role for those two groups, which both of these groups provide in their hierarchy and use that common role instead.

Comment: The suggestion below is less flexible. I wonder what is wrong with my configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what apparently happens, is, that all of the roles mentioned are required, i.e. **both** `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` as well as `ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN`. As far as I understand your problem description, your user is **either**, but not both.

The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBrnr.png) you provided shows the access manager handling the request at the bottom:
[image]

which clearly shows, that the `AuthenticatedVoter` is NOT the problem, because it abstains (since it only votes on `IS_AUTHENTICATED_*` roles (for example `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`), which is also easily seen in [its code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4b8983aef59afb579c3941f103e74ef98e5f9d22/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/AuthenticatedVoter.php#L46-L50).

However, as can be easily seen as well, **both** roles are checked separately(!). The RoleHierarchyVoter now tries to see, if the `ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN` is granted, and I assume your user has the `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`, which the RoleHierarchyVoter will expand by using the hierarchy to `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`,`ROLE_ADMIN_CAN_EDIT_PERMISSIONS`, `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_USER`. None of which is `ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN`.

As I have suggested in a comment, you might want to choose to add a new ROLE that *both* extended admin roles hold. if `ROLE_ADMIN` is not appropriate, maybe a `ROLE_EXTENDED_ADMIN` or something.

```
ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_EXTENDED_ADMIN]
ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN_CAN_EDIT_PERMISSIONS, ROLE_EXTENDED_ADMIN]
```

and then in access control:

```
 - { path: ^/admin/select-customer-status, roles: ROLE_EXTENDED_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Many thanks! You opened my eyes on the real problem. I've added to a user both roles in database, like that `a:2:{i:0;s:19:"ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN";i:1;s:16:"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN";}` and it works as expected.

Comment: @SerhiiPopov btw: roles are tricky, changing them while the user is logged in might not work, since the roles are stored in the sessions during the session. relogin will lead to the expected results. just in case ;o)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```php
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;

/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') or has_role('ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN')")
 */

that's all
```